# Google Play Services 4.1 documentation?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

It's been almost a week since Google Play Services 4.1 has been announced. And I am very much interested in the Turn based multiplayer feature introduced in this.

But I cannot find any official documentation or implementation guide for this.
Does anyone has any info on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming soon! Sorry for the delay. Keep an eye on this page:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I can see it published now here (https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer).

Comment: @bruno oliveira Hi, on a slightly unrelated note, why can't I import **com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.*** in my project but I can import **com.google.android.gms.games.realtime.***?

Answer (score 0):

All I know is this:
http://www.engadget.com/2014/01/10/google-play-services-update/ 
But docu seems to remain the same for now.